# Office Web Apps SharePoint 2013 compatibility with Edge

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, owa, edge

I have recently upgraded to Windows 10 and I am trying to open documents in my SP 2013 environment with Office Web Apps. They open fine when it comes to IE 11 and Chrome but it is giving me an error that it can't open the document. Is Edge compatible with OWA or do i have to reconfigure the OWA server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official article, use the most recent versions of the following browsers for the best experience with Office for the web:

Windows 10: Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer 11, Mozilla Firefox, or Google Chrome

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/which-browsers-work-with-office-for-the-web-ad1303e0-a318-47aa-b409-d3a5eb44e452

What is the error message you got? Please offer a screenshot.

Clear browser cache and compare the results.